# Debugger does not start in VSCode for Django

Tags: python, django, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug my Django project, but whenever I hit the play button on the run and debug window in VSCode, it thinks for a second, and then completely stops. My project runs completely fine when I run it with the "runserver" command.

I've tried restarting VSCode, and restarting my computer.

here is my launch.json file

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "9000"
            ],
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this help :

Ctrl + Shift + P
Python: Select interpreter

Choose the right one